# Tomcat7 failed to deploy a web application CSRF Token

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I developed java application using spring mvc and spring security.
and when i upload and deploy the `WAR` file on tomcat7 it fails and give me this messages in the url:

```
manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=982F861CA67920658BC340994D5B7A32
```

How can i fix the problem and upload my web application properly ?

[EDITED]
My code:

```
  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <csrf/>
    <!-- custom login -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login" username-parameter="custom_email"
                password-parameter="custom_password" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/>
    <remember-me key="remember-me"/>

    <!-- css and js-->
    <intercept-url pattern="resources/cms/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="resources/home/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/wro/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/cms/**" requires-channel="any" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/account/**" requires-channel="any" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/cart/**" requires-channel="any" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/checkout/**" requires-channel="any" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login"/>
    <!--<csrf disabled="true"/>-->

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: This may not be related to spring-security at all. What is the actual error message? What does Tomcat log files say?

Comment: yeah i know .

In the log file was the same message i posted which is:
org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=982F861CA67920658BC340994D5B7A32

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Spring-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
       ...
       <csrf disabled="true"/>          
</http>
```

Comment: Although i tried your solution and it didn't work, it doesn't make scenes ... i do want my application to be CSRF protected!.

Comment: Ok, then you can do:

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
       ...
       <csrf />          
</http>

If this not solve your problem, please post more of your code.

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: ok checkout my security-context.xml i have edited my question.

Comment: Move your <csrf/> declaration to the end of http tag

Comment: Think you have to "enable" csrf in your jsp, thymeleaf web site as well

Comment: Guys i tried to disable the CSRF and it didn't work.. so i don't think it's from it

Comment: Can you post your server log when you try to upload the war file?

Comment: The log file has the same message i posted in the question.

Comment: Have you by any chance used @EnableWebSecurity in your java configuration class (extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter) and there might be some sort of csrf property overriding. You might want to check that

Comment: I use xml to enable my security configuration...look at my xml file in the question please.